# Cordova loading app into android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, cordova

I am totally new to Cordova, but now I have installed Cordova with NPM and installed Android SDK and set up an AVD which seems to work perfectly, until I want to emulate my project. Where the actual app for some reason is not loaded into the emulator.

The following action is done:

```
marvin:HelloWorld$ cordova -d emulate android
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Wrote out Android application name to "HelloWorld"
Wrote out Android package name to "com.example.hello"
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
Preparing android project...
Processing configuration changes for plugins.
Iterating over installed plugins: []
Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
Running on emulator for platform "android" via command ""/home/marvin/Development/projects/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/run" --emulator" (output to follow)...
```

Then it start Android emulator up, but the app is not there. Does anybody have a suggestion to fix this issue, so I am capable of actually testing in my emulator?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and I was missing PATH to platform-tools in android sdk folder, after I added it everything was in place.

Comment: Where did you add this to?

Comment: If you are using a mac you can edit .bash_profile and set the path there. On windows, edit environment variables and add append to the PATH there.

Comment: I did that already,... I have the variabled named as PATH inside the System Variable (windows). And the location is "D:\apps\installed\adt-x86x64\sdk\platform-tools" but still once the emulator run... there's no app launched. Any other clue? @mirazasx

Comment: I am having this issue with IOS emulator. No app is appearing, even if it's just a blank new Cordova project. Any idea on how to fix that? On Mac.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as well; I could run the `cordova emulate android` command just fine, and the emulator would eventually start up and function, however, the test app was never installed on the device. I was not getting any errors from the Cordova CLI or the console or anything.

I found that there is a bug report about this issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4285

Two solutions have been found for this issue: 
 1. Make sure you are using an Oracle JDK and not an IBM JDK, and
 2. Make sure the AVD that emulate starts up has a min-target-sdk set to API 10 (Android 2.3.3) or higher. (This was my problem.)

Comment: This worked for me, bumped the AVD to 4.2.2: "Make sure the AVD that emulate starts up has a min-target-sdk set to API 10 (Android 2.3.3) or higher."

Comment: i'm using API Level of 16. But same problem. No app launched, any clue @Ricky ?

Answer (score 3):

*Sometimes* it works deleting the previously installed version of the app in the emulator. For this you could also launch it with the option "Wipe user data" checked.

Just for the record, none of the other solutions worked for me.

Comment: Running the avd with the emulator option `Snapshot` **off/unchecked** or manually starting the target with `Wipe user data` **checked/on**  works for me. I haven't yet found a way to do the latter wipe option from the `cordova emulate` command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Following solved it for me.

Make sure that API level of your AVD is greater than minSdkVersion specified in config.xml specified in your cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still having this issue:

I had a same problem with device being offline.

if ddms is running it looks after connected devices.

```
adb kill server
```

and than run `ddms`

Comment: The standalone version of DDMS is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your app id doesn't begin with a number or any other character like "_". For example, if your app id is `com.4company.MyApp` or `com._company.MyApp` it just won't load on the emulator. The first one is because [Java doesn't allow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) names beginning with a number, and the second one I guess it's a Cordova thing.

You should also use `adb logcat` to show the emulator errors on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the app was not starting up because I had a second emulator running in the background.  Uninstalling bluestacks (android emulator for windows) fixed the issue in my case.  Running "adb logcat" should tell you if you have multiple emulators running.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and It was my emulator device that was with the API 15. Just updated to API 17 and the problem solved.